# Output multiple days from today

Tags: php

I'm building a dropdown with all the available schedule for the week.
I got this code here that shows the Saturdays from today.

```
<?php
$dow   = 'saturday';
$step  = 1;
$unit  = 'W';

$start = new DateTime('N');
$end   = clone $start;
$start->modify($dow);

$end->add(new DateInterval('P1M'));

$interval = new DateInterval("P{$step}{$unit}");
$period   = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);

foreach ($period as $date) {
    echo $date->format('D, d M Y'), PHP_EOL;
}
```

Now what I want to achieve is something like this:

```
 March 5, 2018 (Monday) at 2:00pm
 March 5, 2018 (Monday) at 7:00pm
 March 7, 2018 (Wednesday) at 2:00pm
 March 7, 2018 (Wednesday) at 7:00pm
 March 10, 2018 (Saturday) at 2:00pm
 March 10, 2018 (Saturday) at 7:00pm
 March 12, 2018 (Monday) at 2:00pm
 March 12, 2018 (Monday) at 7:00pm
 March 14, 2018 (Wednesday) at 2:00pm
 March 14, 2018 (Wednesday) at 7:00pm
 March 17, 2018 (Saturday) at 2:00pm
 March 17, 2018 (Saturday) at 7:00pm
```

The time is pretty much constant and it would be nice to include a filter to remove specific days when needed. How do I go about this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try something like this:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$days_to_display = ['Monday', 'Saturday'];
$times_to_display = [14, 19];
$dates_to_exclude = ['2018-03-19'];

$startTime = new DateTime();
$currentTime = clone $startTime;
$endTime = clone $startTime;
$endTime->add(new DateInterval('P1M')); // For the next month

while($currentTime <= $endTime) {
    if (
        in_array($currentTime->format('l'), $days_to_display) &&
        !in_array($currentTime->format('Y-m-d'), $dates_to_exclude)
    ) {
        foreach($times_to_display as $hour) {
            $currentTime->setTime($hour, 0, 0);
            echo $currentTime->format('F j, Y (l) \a\t g:ia') . "\n";
        }
    }
    $currentTime->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
}
```

This results in the output:

`March 10, 2018 (Saturday) at 2:00pm
March 10, 2018 (Saturday) at 7:00pm
March 12, 2018 (Monday) at 2:00pm
March 12, 2018 (Monday) at 7:00pm
March 17, 2018 (Saturday) at 2:00pm
March 17, 2018 (Saturday) at 7:00pm
March 24, 2018 (Saturday) at 2:00pm
March 24, 2018 (Saturday) at 7:00pm
March 26, 2018 (Monday) at 2:00pm
March 26, 2018 (Monday) at 7:00pm
March 31, 2018 (Saturday) at 2:00pm
March 31, 2018 (Saturday) at 7:00pm
April 2, 2018 (Monday) at 2:00pm
April 2, 2018 (Monday) at 7:00pm`

The key for me is incrementing a counter date until you find a day you're happy with. This is not particularly efficient (as it loops through every day), but should suffice for what you're looking for.